Python TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
I am getting the following error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/etd.py", line 77, in lambda_handler
    data = pd.concat(concated_data, ignore_index=True)

In the following block:
for idx, day_row in curr_df.iterrows():
    av_last_month, rate_end_last_mon = last_months_avs(df_to_date, day_row['From_Currency'], day_row['To_Currency'], day_row['Obs_Date'])

concated_data = ({'Obs_Date': day_row['Obs_Date'], 'From_Currency': day_row['From_Currency'], 
'To_Currency': day_row['To_Currency'], 'Rate': day_row['Rate'],
'PE_Rate': av_last_month, 'Mon_End_Rate': rate_end_last_mon})

data = pd.concat(concated_data, ignore_index=True)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)


What's the question? Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. If you're looking for help with your code, you need to make a [mre]. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

The first argument to pd.concat() is supposed to be a sequence of dataframes to combine. You have a dictionary. What are you trying to concatenate with what?

Usually it's something like pd.concat([df1, df2]). See the examples in the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

One of your values is a string and not a Series or a DataFrame:
concated_data = ({'key1': pd.Series(), 'key2': pd.Series()})
pd.concat(concated_data, ignore_index=True)

# Output
Series([], dtype: object)

However:
concated_data = ({'key1': pd.Series(), 'key2': pd.Series(), 'key3': ''})
pd.concat(concated_data, ignore_index=True)

# Output
...
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

To debug, try:
for key, val in concated_data.items():
    print(key, type(val))

# Output
key1 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
key2 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
key3 <class 'str'>

Note: I think you should also use axis=1 as argument of pd.concat.
